# Load balanced for SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

I have 4 machines, M1 is running window form app, M2 is running a website application, M3 and M4 is running SymmetricDS. M1 connects to M2 as order to sync data.

How can I config M3 or M4 as load balanced server?

Comment: Are M3 and M4 connecting to the same database?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Where is SymmetricDS currently installed and which databases are they syncing?

Comment: M3 and M4 are connecting to the same DB in M1. SymmetricDS was installed in M3 and M4